# Scala type class for obtaining the most concrete type for a type member

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless

Consider the following Scala code:

```scala
trait Elem
class MyElem extends Elem

trait Holder {
  type EP <: Elem
  def get: EP
}

class MyHolder(e: MyElem) extends Holder {
  type EP = MyElem
  def get = e
}
```

Depending on whether I have an object typed `Holder` or `MyHolder`, calling `get` may return an `Elem` or `MyElem`, respectively. I'm trying to make that information available at type level, but I'm not getting any results. Consider, for example, a `Getter` type class like this:

```scala
trait Getter[From] {
  type Out
  def get(from: From): Out
}

object Getter {
  type Aux[From, Out0] = Getter[From] { type Out = Out0 }

  def apply[From](implicit getter: Getter[From]): Getter.Aux[From, getter.Out] = getter

  // some way to create a `Getter[H <: Holder]`
  // where `Out` is the most specific type known for `H#EC`
}

Getter[MyHolder] // should return a MyHolder { type Out = MyElem }
Getter[Holder] // should return a Holder { type Out = Elem }
```

I'm trying to create the implicit constructor for `Getter[H <: Holder]` missing in the snippet but even though I tried several ways of constraining the types, I'm not getting any results that work for both examples above.

Is this possible to do with the Scala compiler? Does any type class from `shapeless` or `scalaz` help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking sounds like an application of [Path Dependent Types](http://gigiigig.github.io/tlp-step-by-step/dependent-types.html)

Wherein you can type something based on the type defined in some trait/class without knowing the concrete implementation:

```
val x: Holder#EP = ???
```

I hope this is what you're looking for, if not I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: Hi Charles. I already thought of using path-dependent types and they can be used to solve the problem in the question. Unfortunately, they won't work in my specific problem as it's slightly more complicated than the example I gave here. Nonetheless, if you improve your response to provide an implementation for the problem above, together with a brief explanation, I'm willing to accept your answer here.